# exclude fields from import-csv

Tags: powershell

I have a CSV file that I want to import so that I can filter out some of the records. I can do that with a where-object cmdlet. However, I'd also like to leave out some of the fields either at import time or when outputting to a new CSV file. Any suggestions?
I've tried `Select-Object -excludeProperty` and `.psobject.properties.Remove()` to delete them after importing to a variable. Either I didn't do it right or that doesn't work because if I do `$var | Get-Member`, it still shows the properties.

Comment: `Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty propertyName`

Comment: I still don't know why I need the *, but that made the difference. Thanks.

Comment: The `*` is a wildcard for everything and being used for the [positional parameter](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554301.aspx) `Property`, basically you're selecting everything and then excluding specific properties. If you name the parameter, the full command would be: `Select-Object -Property * -ExcludeProperty propertyName`